# How to Implement this special selector?

Tags: verilog, vhdl

Is it possible to write a module with 3 wires a,b,c that would output either :

1. z (disconnected) if a=b=c=z
2. a if a=(0 or 1) and b=c=z
3. b if b=(0 or 1) and a=c=z
4. c if c=(0 or 1) and a=b=z
5. x (dont care) otherwise

In verilog?

Comment: Verilog aside, how would you physically find out if the input to a logic gate is high impedance?  How would you implement that detection if you only had logic gates and flip flops/latches?

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't, because `z` isn't a condition that can be tested for in synthesizable logic. You'd need to find a way to convert the concept of "`z` or not-`z`" into a logic level.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on why high impedance isn't a condition that can be checked for:

When a signal is high impedance, the FPGA just leaves that signal floating. Usually if you drive a signal to `0`, it will connect it to `GND`, if you assign `1` it will connect it to `VCC`. By assigning `Z`, you're telling the FPGA to leave it floating and not pulled up or down. In this state, the signal is in an indeterminable value, because the CMOS/TTL circuitry that determines if a signal is a `1` or a `0` is not designed to work with floating signals.

So what's the point? Why have high impedance signals in the first place?

Say for example that on your board the signal is connected to one of the output pins, and the external circuitry connects it to `GND`. By leaving the signal at high impedance, you're allowing the external circuitry to do the pulling down. In this case, if you were to set the signal as `Z`, you would still be able to determine its value by checking if it's a `1` or a `0`, because even though you on the FPGA haven't pulled it down, it's been pulled down elsewhere in the circuitry.

So when you're doing signal assignments, assigning to `z` is something that's done regularly. However, when you're checking signals, you shouldn't be checking for `z`, but rather for `1` or `0` depending on the expected behaviour of whoever really is driving them.

Answer (score 0):

```
always @(in1,in2,in3) begin
     case ({in1,in2,in3}) 
      3'bzzz:  data_out = 1'bz;
      3'b0zz:  data_out = 1'b0;
      3'bz0z:  data_out = 1'b0;
      3'bzz0:  data_out = 1'b0;
      3'b1zz:  data_out = 1'b1;
      3'bz1z:  data_out = 1'b1;
      3'bzz1:  data_out = 1'b1;
      endcase
end
```

this seem to work...

Comment: It may work in simulation but it will not work on FPGA or IC. And FYI you need to add `default: data_out = 1'bx;` to your case statement for full behavioral non-synthesizable functionality.